# Oracle SQL XMLAGG &quote; Issue

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am trying to aggregate A into a list of dictionaries. Oracle's `LISTAGG()` works but does run into the 4k max char limit. I tried with `XMLAGG` but now I'm getting "and quot;" instead of "". Please suggest the best way of resolving this. `XMLCAST` ? Will the final outputs of `listagg()` and the work around be identical ?

| A | N |
| --- | --- |
| {"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","5":""} | 1 |
| {"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","6":""} | 2 |
| {"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","7":""} | 3 |

```
select  
  --        '[' ||
  --        LISTAGG(cte.A, ' , ') WITHIN GROUP(
  --                ORDER BY
  --                    cte.N
  --            )
  --            || ']'
  '[' ||
  rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,cte.A,', ').extract('//text()') order by cte.N).getclobval(),', ')
  || ']' aggr_lsts
from cte;
```

Bad Output:

```
[{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;09&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;2010&quot;,&quot;4&quot;:&quot;XYZ&quot;,&quot;5&quot;:&quot;&quot;}, {&quot;1&quot;:&quot;09&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;2010&quot;,&quot;4&quot;:&quot;XYZ&quot;,&quot;6&quot;:&quot;&quot;}, {&quot;1&quot;:&quot;09&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;2010&quot;,&quot;4&quot;:&quot;XYZ&quot;,&quot;7&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]
```

Good Output:

```
[{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","5":""} , {"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","6":""} , {"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","7":""}]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could not post that table without formatting as code!

Comment: You can achieve much more with JSON functions with this kind of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`xmlcast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLCAST.html#GUID-06563B93-1247-4F0C-B6BE-42DB3B1DB069) function to correctly deserialize XML data as a clob.

Please note, that XMLType methods are [deprecated since Oracle 11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/changes.htm#ADXDB6162), so use `XMLQUERY` and `XMLCAST` instead.

```
with sample(col, rn) as (
  select column_value, rownum
  from sys.odcivarchar2list(
    '&',
    '>',
    '<',
    '"',
    'correctly serializable text'
  )
)
select
  rtrim(xmlcast(xmlquery(
    '//text()'
    passing xmlagg(
      xmlelement(e,col,', ')
      order by rn
    )
  returning content
  ) as clob), ', ') as res
from sample
```

| RES |
| --- |
| &, >, <, ", correctly serializable text |

But for 12.2 and above you may use JSON functions directly to produce correct JSON array: [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054) (with a restriction on 32k JSON keys per object, if I remember correctly).

```
with sample(col, rn) as (
  select column_value, rownum
  from sys.odcivarchar2list(
    '{"a": 1, "b": "2"}',
    '{"a": 2, "b": "qwe"}',
    '{"a": 3, "c": "test"}'
  )
)
select
  json_arrayagg(
    col order by rn
  ) as res
from sample
```

| RES |
| --- |
| ["{"a": 1, "b": "2"}","{"a": 2, "b": "qwe"}","{"a": 3, "c": "test"}"] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oy6aib3j)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use XML functions with JSON data. From Oracle 12.2, use `JSONAGG` to aggregate the rows:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(a FORMAT JSON ORDER BY n RETURNING CLOB) As output
FROM   table_name
```

*Note: you need `FORMAT JSON` to treat your input as valid JSON, otherwise it will be treated as a string and quoted. You also need `RETURNING CLOB` otherwise the default return type is a `VARCHAR2` which is limited to 4000 characters and will give you the same issues as `LISTAGG`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (A, N) AS
SELECT '{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","5":""}', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","6":""}', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","7":""}', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| [{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","5":""},{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","6":""},{"1":"09","2":"11","3":"2010","4":"XYZ","7":""}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XgUb0J3F)